# Maxima with equality constraints

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

I am trying to create an algorithm that finds the global maximum to a function with (in)equality constraints numerically. However, I am trying to fit that into a webpage (for example, via javascript.

So there are 2 things I can try:

1. Try to include a CAS with javascript/php/etc. (this is a non-Math.SE thing)
2. Write such an algorithm myself.

I know quite a bit about my function (which is 22-dimensional), I have the exact term which depends on several additional parameters that can be replaced by actual values before evaluating. The function itself is just a product of fractions of terms that are linear in every variable, for example $$\frac{a+b}{c-d+p_1}\cdot\frac{e+f\;p_2}{g}\cdot\frac{p_3}{h}$$
($a,\cdots,g$ are variables, $p_1,p_2,p_3$ are constants)
And the function does not have singularities in the allowed boundaries.

My equality constraints are just of the form $a+b+c+d+e=9$ and $a\ge0, \;b\ge0,\;...$

Mathematica can find the extremas to any given precision within very short times, however it cannot find a general form in dependency of all constants.

Calculating the gradient of my function is not a problem either, solving the 26-dimensional non-linear equation system is however. Therefore, I guess the approach via laplacian coefficients is non-viable. The function appears to be neither concave nor convex, as many solving methods rely on this information, I am kinda stuck here.

On top of that, I am actually only searching for integer solutions (I am happy with real-valued solutions anyways, several tests show that the solutions tended to be nearly integer-valued anyways), however I calculated that there is a total of 57314457200 ways to fill in the variables while fulfilling the constraints (brute-forcing falls out here) and I do not know much about mixed-integer optimization.

So my main questions are:

- Are there any algorithms that efficiently and easily solve this problem?
- How does one handle the fact that there are 22 inequality constraints, which have to be turned on and off in turn, resulting in a total of $2^{22}=4194304$ problems that have to be solved?

I am happy with partial solutions and keywords. I am sure that there is such a solution, (as Mathematica reliably calculates the optimums) however I would be glad not to be forced to write/include a full CAS for this.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried to write KKT conditions ?

Comment: In order for the KKT rules to apply in a way that can ensure to find the global maximum, the function has to be convex. It isnt, however; On top of that, I have stated that solving the equations analytically will not be feasible; Thank you anyways.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. For non convex problems the KKT conditions are not sufficient. So writting the conditions will only give you stationnary points, then you'll have to test them.

Comment: As to this specific case, I have found a better solution: I remembered this is basically some kind of "Knapsack problem" (as I am searching for integer solutions). This can be solved algorithmically. However, I am still interested in actual solutions to the question stated above. Thank you.